# How to find element in vector from right to left

Tags: c++, stl

there is in standart library `find` function, but it searches first match from left to right, how I can find element from right to left with using standart library?

```
std::vector<T> values;
std::find(values.begin(), values.end(), x); // searching from left to right
```

Comment: reverse iteration, should be in your C++ book

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you! how could I forget this:))

Comment: If I could remember all the things I forgot I'd probably run out of RAM.

Comment: I wonder what left and right is in a vector...

Comment: @Klaus and if you iterate three times to the left, do you go right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to find not the *first* instance of a value in your vector, but the last?

`std::find` takes all kinds of iterators (so far as I'm aware), so you could use `rbegin()` and `rend()` to reverse iterate through your vector instead.  That is:

```cpp
std::vector<T> values;
auto it = std::find(values.rbegin(), values.rend(), x); // searches from right to left
```

You just gotta be careful that you're checking against `rend()` and not `end()` when you are confirming whether your `find` operation returned any results.

Answer (score 4):

You might use reserse_iterator:

```
std::find(values.rbegin(), values.rend(), x);
```